# Lambda Function URL in a public subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-vpc

**Note:** I am **NOT** asking why a Lambda in a subnet cannot access the public internet.

I would like to host a Lambda function, with the Function URL enabled, in a public subnet and expose it via CloudFront. This is so that the function can be called from the broader internet but also access private resources.

Is this possible?

I have tried creating a very simple Lambda (the default generated by the `serverless.AspNetCoreMinimalAPI` template) and uploading to a simple function with Function URL enabled. With just that, I can call the Lambda from (eg) Postman.

The moment I attach it to the public subnet of my VPC I get `502 Bad gateway` even with an Internet Gateway attached to the VPC.

Comment: The function URL is always outside the VPC. The Lambda function itself is not sitting there listening for HTTP requests. There is some service running outside of your AWS account, in the general AWS infrastructure, that is listening for requests, and when a request comes in on that URL it invokes an instance of your Lambda function. I don't see why adding the function to the VPC should break that. Did you give the function the appropriate execution role to allow it to run in a VPC? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html Can you run the function via the AWS console?

Comment: Yes, it already has the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole role.
Wouldn't putting the Lambda in a VPC necessarily prevent access to it's Function URL? Surely that would simply make the URL visible to only those with access to the VPC? Otherwise, the function would still be open to the world.

Comment: "Wouldn't putting the Lambda in a VPC necessarily prevent access to it's Function URL? Surely that would simply make the URL visible to only those with access to the VPC?" No. Please re-read what I posted earlier. The service that handles the URL is on the public Internet, it is not in your VPC. That service triggers invocations of your Lambda function.

Comment: "The moment I attach it to the public subnet of my VPC I get 502 Bad gateway even with an Internet Gateway attached to the VPC.".. how are you invoking it?

Comment: @paolo Just in a browser or Postman

Comment: @paolo I do not know what has changed, but now, when connecting a Lambda function to a VPC with Function URL enabled, I cannot seem to break it. Even without an internet gateway, NAT gateway and with the routing tables removed from the subnets, I can still invoke the Function URL  when it is attached to the private subnets. Have I badly misunderstood the way VPCs work?

Comment: No, you've misunderstood how the function URL works. See my answer to your other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to add a NAT Gateway to your VPC and attach it to your public subnet. Then you need to add a route to your route table to route all traffic to the NAT Gateway. You can find more information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

Comment: I thought that putting the Lambda in a public subnet would allocate it a public IP and it would be accessible from the internet?

Comment: No, it will not. Lambda functions are not accessible from the internet. They are only accessible from within the VPC.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding a new VPC and placing the Lambda in the public subnet. This broke public access to it's Function URL. When I added the NAT to the public subnet, access was restored. This appears to be what I'm looking for. I need to retry this to make sure I have it constructed properly, but thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I read your question a few times to make sure I understand what you are trying to do. The way you ask the question, the answer is no.

If you take out the CloudFront requirement, then of course [it is possible and it works perfectly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html); you can easily access the lambda URL from anywhere, including the Internet. With the CloudFront requirement, it is still possible to achieve what you're trying to do, but you have to do it in a different manner. The URL to be accessed is not the URL of the lambda function; you have to access the URL of the CloudFront distribution and when you do that it triggers your lambda function to run from the CloudFront distribution edge locations and this is the reason the usage of a lambda function is this case is called [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/). Now, don't let that confuse you; it's just a regular lambda function that gets deployed to the CloudFront distribution edge locations. The main steps to implement what you're looking for are:

- Create a CloudFront distribution
- Create your function [*You are limited to NodeJS and Python*]
- Add a CloudFront trigger to run the function

For detailed instructions, [follow the steps outline here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works-tutorial.html#lambda-edge-how-it-works-tutorial-cloudfront). I am sure it will work.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't believe that Lambda functions run @Edge simply because they have a CloudFront trigger attached. They can, but adding Cloudfront as a trigger simply adds the function as an origin. Deploying a function to Lambda@Edge requires the function to be Node.js or Python and mine is .NET.

Comment: @MattW how else do you run them? I would like to find out; that's the only way I know of. Thanks.

Comment: @DanM There is no other way. Lambda@Edge goes with CoudFront and that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **API gateway** in front of your **Lambda**, and keep all your ressources in private subnet (to keep them fully secured).
You'll no longer need a public url for your lambda, the api gateway has mapping routes, so you can use them.
You may add a cloudFront to the api gateway, only if you need to expose other static contents or api's. If not, you can use a Route53 - a custom domain name - attached to your api gateway. And it'll be fully enough

Comment: This is the opposite of what I want to do. I want to use the Function URL to circumvent needing to create an API Gateway, but I want the Lambda to have access to VPC (private) resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating VPC endpoints for your existing VPC according to [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html).

Interface VPC endpoints allow communication with AWS services from your VPC without requiring access to the public internet. Traffic to the configured service will be routed through the endpoint directly to the service.

Another approach is to have NAT Gateway to your VPC which enables your lambda to be accessed through your public subnet. You may need to have route specified in route table. Also having Nat gateway would cost you little more compared to VPC endpoints.

Comment: Thank you, but I do want to provide public access to the function URL, not just from my own VPCs.

Comment: You can also specify AuthType for functionUrl as NONE. refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html